# Finding the basis given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I had this question in the check your understanding section of my textbook. Say that lily is using the standard basis {$\vec{e_1}, \vec{e_2}$} which correspond to $\vec{e_1} = (1, 0)$ and $\vec{e_2} = (0, 1)$. Now the question goes to say that lily and max are arguing about whose coordinates are right. You are asked to explain who is right or wrong. Both of them are right since they are using different basis to describe the plate and mug's coordinates. I have max's vectors in his basis but i dont know his basis vectors. I dont know how to find them using lily's vectors and the basis she uses. It asks to solve using linear combinations if possible. I also notice the grid has gone a 90 degree rotation clockwise.

[image]

Comment: I think you're leaving out details about the problem.

Comment: @RyanGreyling i added the entire question

Comment: Jordan must be a genius.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about Max and Lily using different bases. The question doesn't seem to recquire any calculations, but if you're interested you can convert from coordinates in Lily's space to coordinates in Max's space if you have some matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a && b \\ c && d\end{pmatrix}$ s.t. $$A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\1\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$A\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ and if you solve this system of equations you'll get 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 && -1 \\ 1 && 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ If you want to convert Lily's coordinates to Max's coordinates, you can just apply the inverse of the above matrix.

There's something else that's worth pointing out. Max sees his own basis as $\vec{e_1}=(1,0)^T$ and $\vec{e_2}=(0,1)^T$ but he sees Lily's as $\vec{e_1}=(0,1)^T$ and $\vec{e_2}=(-1,0)^T$. Notice that if you apply our matrix $A$ to Max's basis vectors you get Lily's basis vectors written in Max's coordinates.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I must ask what does that T in the exponent mean??

Comment: The $T$ indicates the transpose operator. So $(0,1)^T$ is the exact same as $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. I chose to write it the first way because I don't like the way column vectors look in the middle of text.